# Laravel - Cannot get Roles for Admin guard

Tags: php, laravel

I have a frontend and admin areas. The frontend using the `Auth` package from Laravel and for the `Admin` I am using an admin `guard` and all views, controller, and models are under `admin` directory.

I am trying to set up the roles and permissions for both frontend and admin users using the same `Role` and `Permission` model. For that, I have created following tables

### Tables

- admins
- permission_role - *pivot*
- permissions
- role_admin - *pivot*
- role_user - *pivot*
- roles
- users

**The problem:** I am able to get roles for the frontend users using `belongsToMany()` but not for the admin. Here is the code.

### User Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function admin_roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin\Role', 'role_admin');
    }

    public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin\Role');
    }
}
```

### Role Model

```
namespace App\Admin;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'display'];

    public function permissions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin\Permission');
    }

    public function admin_users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }

}
```

### Frontend View

```
{{auth()->user()->roles}}

// output 
[{"id":1,"name":"admin","display":"Admin","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"pivot":{"user_id":1,"role_id":1}},{"id":2,"name":"supervisor","display":"Supervisor","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"pivot":{"user_id":1,"role_id":2}}]
```

### Admin View

```
{{auth()->user()->admin_roles}}
//output
null - checked with dd()
```

## Edit

### Table Structure

#### role_admin

```
Schema::create('role_admin', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigInteger('role_id')->unsigned();
    $table->bigInteger('admin_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('admin_id')->references('id')->on('admins')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

#### role_user

```
Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigInteger('role_id')->unsigned();
    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

#### roles

```
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->text('display');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

#### permissions

```
Schema::create('permissions', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('model');
    $table->string('can');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

#### permission_role

```
Schema::create('permission_role', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigInteger('permission_id')->unsigned();
    $table->bigInteger('role_id')->unsigned();

    $table->foreign('permission_id')->references('id')->on('permissions')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

#### admin

```
Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

## Admin Model

```
 <?php

namespace App\Admin;

use App\Notifications\Admin\ResetPasswordNotification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'admin';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }
}
```

## Working Code Is Here

I have set the relationship for the `role_admin` it to the `Admin` model which was wrongly placed in the `User` model before.

```
<?php

namespace App\Admin;

use App\Notifications\Admin\ResetPasswordNotification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'admin';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin\Role', 'role_admin');
    }
}
```

Comment: please specify the third parameter and fourth in your admin roles relationship

Comment: what's your table structure?

Comment: @Qonvex620 do you mean adding pivot/fields?

Comment: @PavelLint please have a look edit question. I have added all required table's schema/migration

Comment: @Qonvex620 I have tried your suggestion `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin\Role', 'role_admin', 'admin_id', 'role_id');` but getting the same `null` result.

Comment: do you have this also in your admins model ? public function admin_roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin\Role', 'role_admin');
    }?

Comment: seems your admin_roles relationship is in your user model not in admin model

Comment: @CodeLover I think you should have `user_id` instead of `admin_id` on your role_admin table, since you're connecting `User` model to it. Then `belongsToMany('App\Admin\Role', 'role_admin')` should work.

Comment: @PavelLint I have tried what you say still getting null. See image https://imgur.com/IlShQFZ

Comment: @CodeLover does the `admins` table exist? You seem to reference it in the migrations, but there's no migration for it.

Comment: Yes admin table exits and have all the users.

Comment: well since you have a separate `admins` table then it makes sense to have a separate `Admin` model I think

Comment: Okay, let me create and try. Should I extend the `User` model? Sorry but new to laravel so need some guidance.

Comment: Folks, extremely sorry. Actually I already have an `Admin` model. I have added code at the end of the question. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your admin_roles relationship is in your User model, but in your migration you had declared the foreign key to admins table. like this one

```
$table->foreign('admin_id')->references('id')->on('admins')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Now, let's assume that you logged as an admin , then your Admin model also should has this relationship.

```
public function admin_roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin\Role', 'role_admin', 'admin_id', 'role_id');
}
```

Comment: OMG, I think I missed something here. Do you mean I should have an `Admin` model that extends the `User` model? Since now I am using the `User` (laravel/auth) model and do not have the `Admin` model.

Comment: then why your foreign key in your migration is in admins table ?

Comment: I have added admin migration on the question. well, I am very new to Laravel and trying to understand the power and complexity of `Eloquent` so here probably I should make an `Admin` model. Is that correct?

Comment: when logging as admin ? what table do you used ? User or Admin table ?

Comment: For admin users, I use `admin` table.

Comment: then whats the use of your user table ?

Comment: The `user` table is for the frontend user. I have separate admin and frontend.

Comment: The you have to change your  admin_roles relationship what I wrote above

Comment: I am really sorry for the confusion due to a lack of my understanding of laravel. I already have an `Admin` model. I have added code to the question. please have a look

Comment: but you are using the User model when you logged as admin right ?

Comment: Yes, you hit the nail. Probably I understand the issue. Let me update my `Admin` model.

Comment: if you wanted to use the Admin model, then in your config > auth, you must change the provider for admins by connecting the model into your Admin model.

Comment: Okay finally, it was my damn stupid mistake due to lack of Laravel understanding. I have added a relationship in the `Admin` model and all done.

Thanks a lot to both of you for the great help.

Comment: Actually, your answer didn't help but one of the comments definitely help to figure out the issue. I will select your answer anyway. Can you please update your answer that mentions clearly that I should have an Admin model and define a relationship for the admin role there? So it will make sense to others in the future.

Comment: I already added at first. Please read it. It says that you must have also that relationship in your admin model

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use the model `User` instead of `Admin`

To recover this:

1. Remove the `admin_roles` relation from the `User` model and place it in the `Admin` model.
2. Modify the `admin_users` relation in the `Roles` model to be connected with the `Admin` model instead of the `User` model, so it should be like that 
   `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Admin\Admin');`

Comment: Cool thanks for the answer, however, I have already resolved the issue with the same as you said.